# ASP.NET CORE / Issue encountered when adding .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>(); in the Startup class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Issue encountered when I try to add the first Migration in the project:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[API.Entities.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[API.Entities.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[API.Entities.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[API.Entities.AppUser]'.)
> Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

The class where is inherited IdentityDbContext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, 
    IdentityUserClaim<int>,AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, 
    IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>
    {

        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
         DbSet<CVUser> UserWithCV { get; set; }

        //Fluent API - used to overwrite the EF Core conventions
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Then I have AppUser, which inherits IdentityUser

Startup Class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            services.AddControllers();
            //Setting up the Identity API
            services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>
            (options =>
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false
            )
            
            .AddRoles<AppRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
            .AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<AppRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>(); //  - here is the problem
                                                         
        }
```

```
.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
```

**this line is causing my issue when trying to add a new migration to the project. Any idea why ?**

My only solution is to remove all of the following: (I'm guessing that Identity will create them by default correctly)
*(If I remove the AddSignInManager I can create the Migration)*

```
.AddRoles<AppRole>()
.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<AppRole>>()
.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
```

What do you think ? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're missing `services.AddAuthentication()`?

Comment: @MartinCostello Thank you. That was it. I cannot believe that simple it was, but still thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Seems that I was missing services.AddAuthentication().**
*Thank you for the help @MartinCostello*